# How can I automate conversion of csv file to macro enabled excel?

Tags: vba, csv, excel-2010

I have a CSV file with many columns that I want to import into Excel, then select the desired columns and plot a chart.

I can do all this within .xlms (macro enabled Excel file) but I want to write a batch script that can automate the conversion of csv to xlsm and then add my macros into it.

Can I add macros to an Excel file if I have them saved outside of Excel as .vbs files?

Option Explicit
On Error Resume Next

ExcelMacroExample

```
Sub ExcelMacroExample() 
Dim xlApp 
'Fire up XL
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 
xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
'Open the csv file and parse it into XL format
xlApp.Workbooks.Open "E:\sysmon.csv", 0, True

'OpenText bombed right away, dont know what is wrong here?
'xlApp.Workbooks.OpenText "E:\\sysmon.csv", , , xlDelimited, xlTextQualifierNone, False, False, False, True

' Save into macro enabled template, previously created with the macro
xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "E:\sysmon.xltm", xlOpenXMLTemplateMacroEnabled

'Run the macro  
'xlApp.Run "Memory"

xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.Close
xlApp.Quit 

Set xlApp = Nothing 
End Sub
```

and my memory macro saved in sysmon.xltm

```
Sub Memory()
'
' Memory Macro
'      
    Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count, 5)).Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLine
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count, 5))
    ActiveChart.PlotArea.Select
    ActiveChart.ApplyLayout (2)
    ActiveChart.ApplyLayout (3)
    ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Select
    ActiveChart.Location Where:=xlLocationAsNewSheet, Name:="Memusage"
    With ActiveWorkbook.PublishObjects.Add(xlSourceChart, "E:\tetsysmon.mht", _
        "Memusage", "", xlHtmlStatic, "tetsysmon_5126", "")
        .Publish (True)
        .AutoRepublish = False
    End With
    ChDir "E:\"
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your csv file and the associated macro will look consistent each time, consider this:

Rather than converting a csv and adding a macro, think about adding data from the csv into an existing excel file with an existing macro. It's a lot easier.

Create the excel file with the macro beforehand. In your script open the existing excel file, update it with the csv data, and 'saveAs' a new file.

If the macro and csv format do change dramatically then this might not be ideal. If you post some sample csv data and vbs then I might be able to give you a more specific answer.

Comment: I have updated my post with the code snippet, can you please help? Thanks!

Comment: I got something to work today, I created an intermediate CSVImporter.xlsm containing a macro to save the csv into xlsm. I then injected the macro (using objworkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(1)) to plot my chart into the above created xlsm and then saved and ran this injected macro inline.